# vs code: file not found when trying to debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, cygwin

I'm trying to debug a main.cpp file that resides in a folder that has spaces in its filename: "Jim and the Skyscrapers".

The error message reads:

> Unable to open 'Jim': File not found

And it also gives me the option of creating this "Jim" file.

The debug process works only if I rename the file to "JimAndTheSkyscrapers" so that it doesn't have any spaces.

The way i reference the path in the launch.json and c_cpp_properties.json files is by using the environment variable: ${workspaceFolder}.

As a debugger, I use cygwin's gdb.

I think the problem is: either the debugger parses filepaths in a manner that doesn't allow spaces, either it's a vs code problem. Knowing which one it is would be of great help.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {"name": "OUTPUT_PATH", "value": "results.txt"}
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.13.26128/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: space is normally a separator, so or you escape it or it does not work. Try 'Jim and the Skyscrapers' or "Jim\ and\ the\ Skyscrapers"

Comment: @matzeri thanks for the input. The problem is that, i'd have to manually specify the path to the project each time I move the folder or rename a folder in the path. That is why the ${workspaceFolder} environment variable is very useful, as it automatically uses the name of the containing folder so you don't have to change anything on remove or rename.

Comment: Try also "${workspaceFolder}"

Comment: @matzeri sorry for the confusion. I edited the post and know you can see that I use "${workspaceFolder}".

Comment: @matzeri do you think the problem is with "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe"? I tried using double backslash instead of forward slash but it didn't work from what I remember. Maybe i'll try again but I don't think that is the problem.